# How can I close Office365 Exchange Powershell connections

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, exchange-server, ps

When I'll connect to Office365 Exchange it comes a error message. How can I close this connections?

Script:

```
$userCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'automation'


$ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $userCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $ExoSession

Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "RoomMailbox" -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DiscoveryMailbox"} | Set-Mailbox -AuditEnabled $true -AuditLogAgeLimit 180 -AuditAdmin Update, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create, UpdateFolderPermission -AuditDelegate Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, Create, UpdateFolderPermissions, MoveToDeletedItems, SendOnBehalf -AuditOwner UpdateFolderPermission, MailboxLogin, Create, SoftDelete, HardDelete, Update, MoveToDeletedItems
```

Error:

```
New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Processing data from remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the 
 following error message: 
 [AuthZRequestId=fe5eb99c-df73-4899-b445-ad91e0ecf1f3][FailureCategory=AuthZ-AuthorizationException] Fail to create a 
 runspace because you have exceeded the maximum number of connections allowed : 3 for the policy party : MaxConcurrency. 
 Please close existing runspace and try again.
 Policy: CN=GlobalThrottlingPolicy_cfaee113-6e8e-4889-aa2c-99baf345f85f,CN=Global Settings,CN=ExchangeLabs,CN=Microsoft 
 Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=eurprd04,DC=prod,DC=outlook,DC=com; 
 LockRemaining: 00:00:00 For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
 At line:4 char:15
 + ... xoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conn ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], 
 PSRemotingTransportException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncorrectProtocolVersion,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Comment: Are you wanting to test if the connection failed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could close/remove the session right **after** you have finished your code :

```
# your code
# ...

if ($ExoSession) { Remove-PSSession -Session $ExoSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } }
```

Or, by adding this line **before** creating a new session to remove all possible existing sessions first:

```
Get-PSSession | Where-Object { $_.ConfigurationName -eq 'Microsoft.Exchange' } | Remove-PSSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Hope that helps